# Replacing url parameter - url gets broken

Tags: javascript, regex, url

http://jsfiddle.net/b2QVT/

```
function paramReplace(name, string) {
    var re    = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    newString = string.replace(re,"");

    alert(newString);
    return newString;                         
}
var name="variety";
var string="http://www.example.com/xyz/test.html?Color=Black&key=dress&variety=Leather";

alert(paramReplace(name, string));

var name = "Color";

alert(paramReplace(name, string));
```

In my fiddle, I am trying to update my url with a javascript function on some event.

Whenever I delete the url param that is adjacent to `?` it is removing `?` and just appending the remaining values, hence in the first alert the url is fine, but with the second function call url is getting broken.

How do I handle this scenario, where the param next to `?` is removed. Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: use `console.log` instead of `alert` - it's bloody annoying.

Comment: Rather than using a regex (and hence having a second problem), try parsing the URL (https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561) then rebuilding it to whatever you need.

Comment: Change strategy not to replace `&param=value` or `?param=value` with empty string, but to replace `param=value&` or `param=value` (last parameter) with empty string. Extra `&` in the end of url will not break it (it will appear if you replace last parameter).

Comment: @scrowler:I know alerts are annoying, but in my case, that is the quick way to debug something, ofcourse I know about console.log, I really do not understand there are 3 upvotes (?) for that comment.

Comment: @  Ulugbek Umirov: leaving & in the end might break the url and also url does not look good.

Comment: @user3610392 because when I opened your fiddle I had to click through 4 alert boxes. If you use console.log, you simply open your debug console (F12) and run the script, showing you all four lines at once without needing to close four alert boxes.

Comment: I feel your argument as just for the sake of commenting.. alerts are widely used as means of debugging across, it is individual's preference to use which method, I feel alerts are quite fast and immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
function paramReplace(url, key, value) {
  var parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = url;

  var re = new RegExp('^' + key + '=', 'i');
  var search = parser.search.substring(1).split('&');

  for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
    if (re.test(search[i])) {
      search[i] = key + '=' + value;
      break;
    }
  }

  parser.search = search.join('&');
  return parser.href;
}

var url = "http://www.example.com/xyz/test.html?Color=Black&key=dress&variety=Leather";

var key = 'variety';
var value = 'modified';
console.log(paramReplace(url, key, value));

var key = 'color';
var value = 'modified';
console.log(paramReplace(url, key, value));
```

This code parses the URL, iterates through the search items and removes the matched key-value pair.

Comment: How to change the above function to accept 3 parameters, third one being the value `paramReplace(name, url,value)` need to find a parameter and replace its value with 'value'?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b2QVT/4/ - above code with 3 params breaking the whole url actually...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed the order of parameters. In the example, the first parameters is the URL, the second is the key, the third is the value. It's up to you which order you define.